# why does the image for app icon disappear after installing the app in device?

Tags: iphone, ios5, icons

i have put the image for app icon in app.but when i install my app till installing it shows me the image but when it gets installed in device the image for the app icon disappears.what could be the solution.

Comment: Just give that image name icon.png

Comment: Or go to plist file and find IconFile and give name there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your projectname.plist file and in IconFile tag just write your icon image name like icon.png and then after remove old application from your device and then install this. it will working.